# Win32 API Window Height Mismatch

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm creating a window and I'm defining the height as 768:

```
RECT windowRect;
windowRect.left = (long)0;
windowRect.right = 1366;
windowRect.top = (long)0;
windowRect.bottom = 768;
```

...and the following styles:

```
dwExStyle = WS_EX_APPWINDOW | WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE;
dwStyle = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU;
```

...and finally doing this:

```
AdjustWindowRectEx(&windowRect, dwStyle, FALSE, dwExStyle);
//windowRect.left = -11;
//windowRect.right = 1377;
//windowRect.top = -38;
//windowRect.bottom = 779;
```

And then I'm creating another window trying to fill the whole screen, like this:

```
hTest = CreateWindow(L"STATIC", L"Testing", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE | SS_BITMAP, 0, 0, windowRect.right - windowRect.left, windowRect.bottom - windowRect.top, hWnd, NULL, hInstance, 0);
```

With width of 1366 and height of 768. My computer's resolution is 1920 x 1080.
The width is perfectly aligned, exactly 1366.
The height is weird though, at 768 there's about a 10px margin below. If I use values up to 779, **nothing** changes, the same 10px margin in the bottom is still there. Then if I change to 780px, it's fully covered.

Why does this happen and what's the best way to deal with this? I'd like to have a window menu with exactly the same client height available.

**EDIT:** I've tried:

```
RECT r;
GetClientRect(hWnd, &r);
//r.right = 1366
//r.bottom = 768
```

I don't know why this weird area in bottom is showing, even though the numbers say it's fine...
It's the black border below (the white area is the new child window I'm creating):

[image: grr border]

Although it's in a bad quality (for size), there's exactly 1366 x 768 pixels of **client** area, which is what I requested in the **CreateWindow** function.
Creating a child window for this main window with 768 pixels of height causes the image above.
Adding a padding at top to check if the top 0 is actually 0 (and it isn't using the title border) shows that it is actually 0, that is, if I add any **positionX** to the child window I see the black background above it.

Comment: When do you create the first window? AdjustWindowRect doesn't actually adjust the window, it just calculates the new values.

Comment: I create after I've used AdjustWindowRect().

Comment: Why are you creating a STATIC control with a BUTTON style?  Did you mean `SS_BITMAP` instead of `BS_BITMAP`?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Comment: This is going to be hard to explain, especially since we have no idea how large the outer window actually is.  Not to mention the Aero appcompat lies that tries to deal with the fat borders.  Start by updating your question with the size you actually asked for as well as the resolution of your monitor and improve the code by actually using the rectangle you get back from AdjustWindowRectEx().

Comment: Edited with the additional info. I was already using the RECT from the function, I typed in a rush and I thought I'd show the resulting values from the calc (right - left, etc)

Comment: Please show the sequence. You should have AdjustWindowRectEx, then CreateWindowEx for the main window.

Comment: Temporarily change SS_BITMAP to SS_WHITERECT to make sure it's not the content of the static control that's wrong.  Have you marked your process as high DPI aware?